# How to increase the number of columns using R in Linux

Tags: r

This may seem menial, but it affects my productivity. I am using R in terminal mode on Linux. Unlike the Windows IDE, Linux limits the number of columns to 80, thus making harder the inspection of data sets. Is there a way to set the max number of columns?

Comment: So none of these solutions seem to work for StatET?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is a function I have in my `~/.Rprofile` file:

```
wideScreen <- function(howWide=Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")) {
  options(width=as.integer(howWide))
}
```

Calling the function without the `howWide` argument sets the column to be the width of your terminal. You can optionally pass in the argument to set the width to an arbitrary number of your choosing.

Almost like Josh's suggestion, but less magic :-)

Comment: It turns out that Josh's works if you actually want to do this from `.Rprofile`, but this doesn't.  Apparently `Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")` doesn't work yet when `.Rprofile` is run.  So this answer is only helpful if you don't want `wideScreen()` called automatically.

Comment: If you want to call `wideScreen()` from .Rprofile so it gets called automatically, you must make sure it's an environment variable.  Try typing  `env | grep COLUMNS` into the terminal and if you don't see anything, then add `export COLUMNS` to your .bash_rc file.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you resize your window after starting R, the COLUMNS env variable isn't updated inside R, so you'll get the wrong width that way.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin: curious: it updates for me on both OSX in a local terminal, and when ssh'd into a compute server (and even through gnu/screen). I can stretch my window, call `wideScreen` and it works, then shrink it, call `wideScreen` and it works again ...

Comment: @SteveLianoglou: Odd, I tested it before commenting and just tested it again. I'm sshing from Cygwin into Linux (Ubuntu).  When I'm just at the bash prompt, and I resize my window, COLUMNS updates in bash (`echo $COLUMNS`).  But if I start a non-GUI R, then do Sys.genenv("COLUMNS"), and resize without exiting R, the COLUMNS env var isn't updated.  And I think that's the way it's supposed to work, I don't think bash is supposed to update env vars of all child processes on resize.  Odd that you're seeing different.  OSX vs Linux maybe?

Comment: @MartinC.Martin: I'm not sure which one is the odd one out here, it makes sense to me that if the environment variable updates from the shell, so too should the variable update when R queries `Sys.getenv` ... seems we need someone to ssh into a linux machine *from a linux machine* to bring the tie breaker ;-) My bet would be on the windows/cygwin combo being the odd-one-out, but I'm obviously biased ;-)

Answer (score 47):

Set it with something like

```
options("width"=200)
```

which is in fact what I have in ~/.Rprofile.  See help(options) for details.

Answer (score 18):

Stealing an idea from Brendan O'Connor's util.R (http://github.com/brendano/dlanalysis/blob/master/util.R), you can get your R terminal to set the default width using the stty command. Remunging his script to work on linux, you get the following sexy 1 liner:

```
options(width=as.integer(system("stty -a | head -n 1 | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/;//'", intern=T)))
```

Comment: For mac 10.8.5 it's
`options(width=as.integer(system("stty -a | head -n 1 | awk '{print $6}'", intern=T)))`

Comment: Also see the answer by @plhn using `tput cols` in a system call.

Answer (score 16):

Insert this line to your `~/.Rprofile`

```
options(width=system("tput cols", intern=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 12):

I use this:

```
wideScreen <- function(howWide=as.numeric(strsplit(system('stty size', intern=T), ' ')[[1]])[2]) {
   options(width=as.integer(howWide))
}
```

Because the `COLUMNS` environment variable, and `tset`, aren't updated when the window is resized, but `stty size` is.

Comment: This seems the most robust approach. Unfortunately it doesn’t work on Windows … but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TK gui, I think the option was `--ui=TK` or something like this.

Or is it a hard requirement to use it in the terminal?