# Increase the width of matrix printout

Tags: r

When loading a matrix consisting of 12 columns into R, and then printing it, the terminal window in OS X cuts the matrix in half, sort to speak, first showing all the rows with the initial 7 columns and then showing all the rows again with the remaining 5 columns. However, I would like it to display ll the columns, rather than dividing it up. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use a bigger terminal(window) or a smaller font?

Comment: @Andrie provided the answer. Would you like to just write it as a proper answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @wildplasser It had nothing to do with the size of my window. It was parsed this way from R.

Comment: You could also use `fix` to fire up the data editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Andrie's answer is good, though sometimes one uses a super duper monitor and 9999 is not enough.  ;-)

Here's my function for setting the display width:

```
setWidth <- function (width = NULL) 
{
    if (is.null(width)) {
        columns <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))   
        if (!is.na(columns)) {
            options(width = columns)
        }
        else {
            options(width = 100)
        }
    }
    else {
        options(width = width)
    }
}
```

[This has been addressed previously, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172485/how-to-increase-the-number-of-columns-using-r-in-linux)

So, to improve on just the changing of width, another trick that I recommend: change the number of digits used in numeric output - set `options(digits = ...)` to a smaller value.  See `?options` for more info.

Comment: I think you should upgrade your monitor.  I use `options(width=1e6)` :-P

Comment: @Andrie the 100 is for my cell phone.  ;)