# How to print an R matrix in terminal to fit a widescreen

Tags: r, ubuntu, printing, terminal, fullscreen

I use R in terminal on a widescreen monitor. When I type `print(matrix(rnorm(10*10),ncol=10))`, it'll print 5 columns on top of each other, whereas I want it to print all 10 columns across the widescreen. Even when I have the terminal maximized, it does not take up the additional widescreen room for printing this matrix.

I am using `Ubuntu` and base `R`.

Comment: If you print first and than maximize the window the output in the terminal doesn't change. Try maximizing the window and printing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html):

```
options(width=111)
print(matrix(rnorm(10*10), ncol=10))
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]        [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]
...

            [,10]
...

options(width=130)
print(matrix(rnorm(10*10), ncol=10))
             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]       [,8]         [,9]       [,10]
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function:

```
wideScreen <- function(howWide=Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")) {
  options(width=as.integer(howWide))
}
```

and then set a value to `wideScreen(1000)`

source: [How to increase the number of columns using R in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172485/how-to-increase-the-number-of-columns-using-r-in-linux)

And here is a code to automatically set it on start up:

https://github.com/brendano/dlanalysis/blob/master/util.R

Comment: does this also work on a paralolla with micro hdmi?