# dplyr print to console is offset

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

```
library(nycflights13)

# print head to console
flights
```

This is what I see:
[image]

This what should happen:
[image]

Is this an `R`, `RStudio`, `dplyr` or some options issue?

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

other attached packages:
[1] nycflights13_0.1   dplyr_0.4.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the number of columns using R in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172485/how-to-increase-the-number-of-columns-using-r-in-linux)

Comment: I can't reproduce this - unless I first print some data and then change the width of the console window. Did you do that perhaps?

Comment: `print.tbl_df` uses the value of `getOption("width")` if that helps debugging

Answer (score 2):

The issue does not originate in your code but is a minor issue/bug in RStudio, which shows the data as if you decreased the width of the console after printing the values by hand. What you can do is increase the width of the console in RStudio by hand again.

However, I have no idea what causes the error or how to resolve it in a nicer way without adjusting it by hand. The error sometimes shows up when printing a large amounts of ordered data (data.frame, data.table, tbl_df etc.) as if RStudio sets the boundaries for printing too tight.

Comment: I can confirm that I can see the same effect as described by the OP. I also suspect that it is an RStudio issue.